# How can I send multiple “user input” to python script from another python script?

Tags: python, input, subprocess, pipe

For example I have this file

```
#file2.py
while True:
    name = input("Your name: ")
    print("Hello ", name)
```

I want to run file2.py from other python file and just send inputs and get outputs.
I used subprocess module and stdin and stdout but it close file2.py after one input and I got error for second input.

Comment: running two processes may be an overkill thing to do depending on what you're doing. are you sure you can't simply define some functions in one file and call these functions in another file? having one file being the center of it

Comment: yes, because file2 needs time to run before enter to while loop and if i try to run entire code every time in one file, in becomes very slow

Comment: [Edit] your question and show your code that uses `subprocess`.

Comment: `import subprocess

child = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'file2.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
child.communicate(b"navid')` I used something like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `import`.
Name the file from which you want to open file2.py as file.py and enter your code there, with `import file2` at where you want file2.py to be opened. Save the file in the same directory as file2.py.
So, file.py should look like this:

```
{code}
import file2
```